# vb.net DateTimePicker remove time 12:00:00 AM

Tags: mysql, vb.net, date, time

im having a problem when viewing date on my listview.

on my SQL its okay that on my column "2016-28-11" that is fine
but when i view it on my listview in vb.net it said that "2016-28-11 12:00:00 am"

on my datetimepicker

Value: 11/28/2016
custom format: yyyy-MM-dd
format: custom

when i save the date it adds that time. can anyone help me?

Comment: It doesn't *add* the time. The time is always there, it is an integral part of the `DateTime` type. Please understand the difference between a value and its string representation. *String representation* you selected for your date picker has no effect on the *value* saved in the database, and the *value* read from the database will be displayed with some default format unless you specifically ask for a different one.

Comment: When you saving data use only Date part. `yourDateTimeValue.Date` which return the date with time value set to midnight 00:00

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you add the date in your listview just use something like that:

```
 Dim NewItem As New ListViewItem
 NewItem.Text = "My Item"
 NewItem.SubItems.Add(mydate.tostring("yyyy-MM-dd"))
 ListView1.Items.Add(NewItem)
```

Just keep in mind `mydate.tostring("yyyy-MM-dd")` where `mydate` is a `datetime`.

Considerate your comments, here is the code:

```
.SubItems.Add(ds.Tables("studnum").Rows(i).Item(4).ToString)
Dim MyDate As DateTime = CDate(ds.Tables("studnum").Rows(i).Item(5).ToString)
.SubItems.Add(MyDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"))
```

Comment: The `ListView` doesn't have a `SubItems` property, only `Items`. Also, you have a typo at the end; you have an extra bracket `)` instead of a double-quote `"`.

Comment: @VisualVincent ehehe thanks for the info :D i write it wrong without Visual Studio

Comment: sorry guys im just new at this. i respect all your post im getting an error it said conversion from string "yyyy-MM-dd" to type 'integer is not valid. :(

Comment: @VAN post your code where you get the error, it will be better to find a solution ;)

Comment: For i As Integer = 0 To ds.Tables("studnum").Rows.Count - 1
                With ListView1.Items.Add(ds.Tables("studnum").Rows(i).Item(0).ToString)
                    .SubItems.Add(ds.Tables("studnum").Rows(i).Item(1).ToString)
                    .SubItems.Add(ds.Tables("studnum").Rows(i).Item(2).ToString)
                    .SubItems.Add(ds.Tables("studnum").Rows(i).Item(3).ToString)
                    .SubItems.Add(ds.Tables("studnum").Rows(i).Item(4).ToString)
                    .SubItems.Add(ds.Tables("studnum").Rows(i).Item(5).ToString)

Comment: the last subitems is my datetimepicker on my listview

Comment: still new to this stuff sorry :)

Comment: No prob, but next time edit your first post, and dont paste here the code because is hard to read. Anyway... if i have good understand.. try something like that:
`.SubItems.Add(ds.Tables("studnum").Rows(i).Item(4).ToString)
                    Dim MyDate As DateTime = CDate(ds.Tables("studnum").Rows(i).Item(5).ToString)
                    .SubItems.Add(MyDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"))`

Comment: You are welcome! dont forget to click on the green check below the up and down vote, at the left of my answer! ;)

Comment: thanks bro :) is there anyway i can keep in touch with you? i really need an expert when like this happens :)

Comment: @VAN im not so expert, but you can even write here :D